# How to selectively use one of packages with the same name?

Tags: python, package

What kind of approach is there or good for designing selective choice for different developing modules. This is a module with the name of '**aaa**'. But other developer made a different version of '**aaa**'. Now I could install both modules in different path, one in path_a($HOME/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aaa) and the other in path_b ( $HOME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aaa). Because many files below path_to/aaa are using the package name '**aaa**', I can't change the package name 'aaa' into 'aaa_v1' and 'aaa_v2', in my opinion. How can I choose selectively one of the different packages (different module but the same name), in python script (better) or out of python script such as control of env PYTHONPATH?

Both are installed so both do not appear in PYTHONPATH. But I think it might be possible by controlling sys.path.

It looks that it can happen in a developing packages and when there are several branches in github. And if you want to use or test several versions, how to manage several packages with the same name?

Comment: have you taken a look at virtual environments? specifically, [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: Oh, it looks good. I will try python venv or anaconda env.